# fix card elements size to same html+Scss+javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sass, responsive-design

I have the following requirement:

[image]

where `image`, `name` and `button` are `regular size`, but mine looks odd and `irregular`. See this:

[image]

Codepen link is: `https://codepen.io/anisharya16/pen/vYLzNMj`

How can I fix this to be `responsive` and `regular card size`, there should be `no changes to HTML`? Need Help.

I am using `HTML`, `SCSS`, `Vanilla Javascript`

Comment: Looks like you need to restrict the name field to a min/max-height.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself, not in a link to a separate website. See [mre].

Comment: @Tim How do i change css to scss in code-snippet while editing ?

Comment: I'm not aware that you can, but you can share your code in the question even if it's not a snippet.

Comment: I gave codepen link for accessibility of developers, but from next time I will post the code with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply below css to card title  **min-height: 60px;**

```
.cards-item__card--title {
font-size: 28px;
min-height: 60px;}
```

Comment: Also add `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to center the name vertically

Comment: min-height property worked with value 65px, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions:

You can define a maximum height with **max-height**

You can set the paragraph to not break the line with **white-space: nowrap;**

For very large names, you can define a "..." so that the name does not go beyond the card's div, using **overflow: hidden;** and **text-overflow: ellipsis;**

Comment: min-height property worked for me. And I will keep in mind your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the ideal is to define a maximum size for your div, the min-height will break if you have a very long name, do a test

Comment: It actually did, then i used `overflow` and `text-overflow` property. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following rules:

```css
.cards-item__card--title {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.667em;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

---

## Demo

You can use template literals to simply your rendering.

```js
const config = {
  url: 'https://api.randomuser.me',
  numberCards: 12,
  genderMale: 'male'
}

render(config)

function render(config) {
  const url = `${config.url}?results=${config.numberCards}&gender=${config.genderMale}`
  
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(apiResponse => {
      // Output API response to console to view.
      //console.log(apiResponse.results);

      // Card Implementation
      var myapp = document.querySelector('.card__wrapper');
      myapp.innerHTML = renderCards(apiResponse.results);
    })
}

function renderCards(users) {
  return `
    <ul class="card__wrapper__maincontent">
      ${users.map(renderCard).join('')}
    </ul>
  `
}

function renderCard(user) {
  return `
    <li class="card__wrapper__maincontent__cards-item">
      <div class="cards-item__card">
        <img class="cards-item__card--image"
          src="${user.picture.large}" alt="lorem ipsum"
          style="width:100px;height:100px">
        <p class="cards-item__card--title">
          ${user.name.first} ${user.name.last}
        </p>
     <a class="cards-item__card--cta">Call</a></div></li>
  `
}
```

```css
:root {
  --background-color: #eee;
  --text-color: #333;
  --card-background: #fff;
  --card-cta-background: #e26d00;
  --card-cta-color: #fff;
  --default-spacing: 20px;
}

// default styling
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

// Card
.card__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
}

.cards-item__card {
  background-color: var(--card-background);
  border-radius: 6px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  padding: var(--default-spacing);
  margin: var(--default-spacing);
  text-align: center;
}

.cards-item__card--image {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.cards-item__card--title {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.667em;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.cards-item__card--cta {
  background-color: var(--card-cta-background);
  color: var(--card-cta-color);
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

// New Class
.card__wrapper__maincontent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .card__wrapper__maincontent__cards-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .card__wrapper__maincontent__cards-item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .card__wrapper__maincontent__cards-item {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .card__wrapper__maincontent__cards-item {
    width: 24%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <main class="card__wrapper"></main>
</section>
```